# Apostrophe showing wrong on rails 2.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-encode

I am trying to render an apostrophe as '  '  ', but instead on the interface, it was being rendered as "&#39"; My code to render apostrophe looks like this:

```
 <% @scheduled_events.each do |event| %>
     title  : '<%= event.title %>',    
 <% end %>
```

event.title on the terminal level, it's something like "Brian's". Intead, it was rendered as Brian"&#39"s;

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not rails case, it's HTML about rendering apostrophe, you can change the way it show with css code, or one quick (Temporary solution) is rendered within  tag

```
<% @scheduled_events.each do |event| %>
     title  : <q>'<%= event.title %>'</q>,    
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work: as '==' will not escape strings

```
title  : '<%== event.title %>',
```